# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host.exe causing bad password attempts after changing password

Tags: windows, visual-studio, tfs, passwords

After changing my password it appears that each time I attempt to access or modify a part of a solution I eventually get locked out of my account.

This is because I am exceeding my threshold of bad login attempts.

In order to solve the problem I have attempted the following:

1. Cleared out my cached credentials
2. Updated my password on all local services running under my account.
3. Signed out of and signed into Visual Studio
4. Signed out of any idle VM instances.

Upon inspecting the security log in the Event Viewer I noticed that I am getting failed login attempts from Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host.exe. The failure reason was "Unknown user name or bad password."

Any tips or guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Is your issue related to TFS? Do you have issues when access TFS?

Comment: It appears to only happen with a solution that contains web projects. I get locked out of my domain account and then do not have access to TFS.

Comment: At which step did you get the error?

Comment: It appears to be occurring when the projects are being initially loaded.

Comment: Do you mean the projects initially loaded in Visual Studio? It seems your issue is not related to TFS.